# jQuery click to show/hide not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently creating a page at [this link](http://www.earlcoding.tumblr.com). I'm using this javascript in my header (below my CSS):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/txc9jrr/yNxmd3lq6/jquery.js">   
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    $tr.add($tr.next('.edit')).toggle();
});
$('.cancel').click(function(){
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    $tr.add($tr.prev('.view')).toggle();
});​
</script>
```

and this HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr class="view">
      <td>
          <a class="toggle" class="icon-button" href="#">Edit</a>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="edit" style="display:none">
      <td>
          hi
          <a class="cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In theory, it should work... However when I implement it into my page, it ceases to function. Does anyone have a clue as to what my problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
<a class="toggle" class="icon-button" href="#">Edit</a>
   // ^--------------^---------------------Cannot define two classes like this
```

to

```
<a class="toggle icon-button" href="#">Edit</a>
 //  ^--------------------------------Try like this
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y7SwE/2/)

Comment: I tried your exact demo code however the same result. It doesn't function. Is there something wrong with my js? Perhaps my jQuery link <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/txc9jrr/yNxmd3lq6/jquery.js"></script>?

Comment: @EarlLarson okay i saw your page, there are couple of errors, script should be included inside head or body tag, you have done neither, secondly i guess you copied directly from jsfiddle, basically fiddle adds a character to last element, so copy from fiddle to notepad and then to your file. lastly check this link http://jsfiddle.net/Xd8ue/,

Comment: @EarlLarson Also a _popupControl() is included outside your body tag, i have rectified it pls check that also.

Comment: Worked like gold! Thanks for the tips Sibu.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){

 if ($(".edit").css('display') == 'none') {

      $(".edit").css('display', 'block');
  }
}
```

i think this will help you